# Github- repository is on remote but not found when pushing

Tags: github

I'm trying to push something to github and I'm getting this error;

```
Robbies-MacBook-Pro:assn-6-huffman-mac user$ git push -u origin master
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/BitMechanic/Stanford-CS106b/Huffman.git/' not found
```

Then when I check I get this;

```
Robbies-MacBook-Pro:assn-6-huffman-mac user$ git remote add origin https://github.com/BitMechanic/Stanford-CS106b/Huffman 

fatal: remote origin already exists.

Robbies-MacBook-Pro:assn-6-huffman-mac user$ git remote -v

origin  https://github.com/BitMechanic/Stanford-CS106b/Huffman.git
(fetch)

origin  https://github.com/BitMechanic/Stanford-CS106b/Huffman.git
(push)
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using https? Generally github operates over ssh, and you'll probably be much happier when you get that set up. Are you by chance coming from mercurial?

Comment: You want the origin URL to read `git@github.com:BitMechanic/Stanford-CS106b/Huffman.git`, i. e. the SSH URL instead of the HTTP one.

Comment: I'm using ssh, I'll try it without the https...

Comment: I tried git remote add origin git@github.com/BitMechanic/Stanford-CS106b/Huffman and got "fatal: remote origin already exists"

Comment: Obviously you need to remove the faulty remote first: `git remote rm origin`.

Comment: Robbies-MacBook-Pro:assn-6-huffman-mac user$ git remote add origin git@github.com/BitMechanic/Stanford-CS106b/Huffman.git
Robbies-MacBook-Pro:assn-6-huffman-mac user$ git push -u origin master
fatal: 'git@github.com/BitMechanic/Stanford-CS106b/Huffman.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: Thats a bit of a mess, sorry- I did it and it says that it doesnt appear to be a git repository...

Answer (score 2):

The proper url to use (for cloning and then pushing through origin) is

```
https://github.com/BitMechanic/Stanford-CS106b.git
```

not:

```
https://github.com/BitMechanic/Stanford-CS106b/Huffman.git
```

`Stanford-CS106b` is a repo, listed in the [BitMechanic's repo page of d](https://github.com/BitMechanic?tab=repositories). `Stanford-CS106b/Huffman` is not.

To fix this, see  [`git remote` commands](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote):

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/BitMechanic/Stanford-CS106b.git
```

or, simpler:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/BitMechanic/Stanford-CS106b.git
```

Comment: @NilsWerner thank you for the edit. Actually `git remote set-url` is simpler in this case ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the

```
$cat .git/config
```

output here for reference.

Sometimes it is better to remove the remotes that are misbehaving from there and re-add it using the git remote add command again.

Comment: [core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 ignorecase = true
 precomposeunicode = false
[remote "origin"]
 url = https://github.com/BitMechanic/Stanford-CS106b/Huffman.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Comment: did you try removing the [remote "origin] and add it back in again using the git remote add command? I think that should work.